# Is there a way to bulk process customer data in Stripe?

Tags: stripe-payments

I have a long list of old customers (>10K) in Stripe for which I would like to give a new trial period. Is there a way to bulk process those or we have to do that manually one by one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this depends entirely on what exactly you mean by 'new trial'. Do these customers have pre-existing Stripe subscriptions?

There's really no way to do this via the dashboard. However if there are no pre-existing subscriptions, you could [programmatically create subscriptions](https://stripe.com/docs/api/subscriptions/create) for each customer object accordingly. You can specify the trial period on the [price](https://stripe.com/docs/api/prices) or on a [per subscription basis](https://stripe.com/docs/billing/subscriptions/trials).

As there are no batch endpoints for these operations, please be wary of the [rate limiting](https://stripe.com/docs/rate-limits) if working with the API in this way